# Practice of splitting a web article in many chunks

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, neologisms

Some sites have the (execrable) custom of splitting a web article in many small chunks. Example: the article starting at

https://es.goodtimepost.com/niagara-falls/

is divided in 38 chunks. In each chunk, a image, between 30 and 110 words and six publicity links.

Somebody has invented a name for this practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One term for split stories on web pages is *slideshows.*

Here’s an article about it:

https://www.businessinsider.com/if-the-web-is-distracting-blame-desperate-publishers-2010-8

The REAL Reason You Get Bombarded With Multiple-Page Articles, Slideshows, And Internal Links

Comment: "desperate [and dumb] publishers"... as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From Google:

**clickbait** /ˈklɪkbeɪt/

noun informal *clickbait; click bait*

> (on the Internet) content whose main purpose is to attract attention and encourage visitors to click on a link to a particular web page.

> "these recent reports of the show's imminent demise are hyperbolic clickbait"

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clickbait):

> **clickbait**

> noun [ U ]

> internet & telecoms   specialized informal

> uk /ˈklɪk.beɪt/ us /ˈklɪk.beɪt/

> articles, photographs, etc. on the internet that are intended to attract attention and encourage people to click on links to particular websites

Comment: Clickbait is a more general abe... phenomenon. Slideshows *include* clickbait. More specifically: clickbait is the final cause of slideshows.